# How to reference a workbook without opening it

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a new workbook, and run some macro inside, at the end will paste the result to the new workbook.

I tried different method to reference other workbooks path because I need the data inside, however, I cant do it correctly. Below is my coding:

```
Sub stepTen()
    Dim wbLinelist As String, wsLinelist As String

    wbLlinelist = "C:\Users\abc\Excel\trial\ppp.xlsx"
    wsLinelist = "Sheet1"

    Dim llStyle As Long
    Dim colllStyle, As String

    With Workbooks(wbLlinelist).Worksheets(wsLinelist)
        llStyle = Application.Match("fire", .Rows(1), 0)
        colllStyle = Split(Cells(1, llStyle).Address, "$")(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Dim colllStyle, As String` is no valid syntax remove the comma.
2. Here `Cells(1, llStyle).Address` it is not specified in which workbook and worksheet the `Cells` object is meant to be. It should start with a dot `.Cells(…)` if you want it to use the `With` statement or you must specify a workbook/worksheet.
3. If `Application.Match("fire", .Rows(1), 0)` does not match it returns an error. So you must check if it matched or errored using the [IsError function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function):

   ```
   If Not IsError(llStyle) Then
       'split
   Else
       'error message
   End If
   ```
4. And finally your main issue is that you cannot use a full path `"C:\Users\abc\Excel\trial\ppp.xlsx"` in `Workbooks(wbLlinelist)`. You must open a workbook using the [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) before you can access it.

   ```
   Dim MyOpenWb As Workbook
   Set MyOpenWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=wbLlinelist) 'you might want to open it read only and set the parameter ReadOnly:=True

   With MyOpenWb.Worksheets(wsLinelist)
       'your code
   End With
   ```
5. Don't forget to close the workbook in the end:

   ```
   MyOpenWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
   ```